# one function wont come up (pop up and datepicker)

Tags: jquery

i was successfull in bring up the datepicker on clicking on text box

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
$(function() { 
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({  maxDate: new Date, minDate: new Date(2007, 6, 12),dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
});
```

And i was also successfull in bringing up the pop over on loading the page ,here is the code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  

    var id = '#dialog';

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});     

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});     

});

 </script>

<style type="text/css">
body {
font-family:verdana;
font-size:15px;
}

a {color:#333; text-decoration:none}
a:hover {color:#ccc; text-decoration:none}

#mask {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
z-index:9000;
background-color:#000;
display:none;
}  
#boxes .window {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
width:440px;
height:200px;
display:none;
z-index:9999;
padding:20px;
}
#boxes #dialog {
width:375px; 
height:203px;
padding:10px;
background-color:#ffffff;
}
</style>
</head><body>
 <h2><a href="http://www.queness.com/">Simple jQuery Modal Window Examples from Queness WebBlog</a></h2>
  <div style="font-size: 10px; color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">Except where otherwise noted, content on this site is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License.</div>

 <div id="boxes">
 <div style="top: 199.5px; left: 551.5px; display: none;" id="dialog" class="window">
 Simple Modal Window | 
 <a href="#" class="close">Close it</a>
 </div>
 <!-- Mask to cover the whole screen -->
  <div style="width: 1478px; height: 602px; display: none; opacity: 0.8;" id="mask">     
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Now i want to both datepicker and pop over in th esame page ,butwhen i have integrtaed it to the same page i found that the pop over is working well where as the datepicker is not coming up.when i have removed the code for pop over the datepicker is cuming up,i am totally confuesd what is happening to my code ,some one out there help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to refer the jQuery twice. Since you already have it in the date picker, you don't need to add it for dialog.

Keep this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and remove this line,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
```

Here is the working code,

http://jsfiddle.net/8vNP7/